# Node.js SQL Server driver issue - fails to install

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, node-sqlserver

I am using Node.JS version v0.10.13.
I am using Python version 2.7.2.
I am using node-gyp version 0.10.2 according to the package.json file.

Output from trying to install node-sqlserver via npm
http://pastebin.com/N262mMR8

Output from trying to install msnodesql via npm
http://pastebin.com/czY4S2Sq

Not sure what next steps I should take to resolve the issue? My machine has Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 installed.

Update: What is the solution for this in the Azure world / Azure Mobile Services?

Comment: Based on this link, there does not seem to be a driver for Node 0.10.x   https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver/issues/126

Comment: I'll looked around and didn't find any articles on this, but any info on what version of Node.js I should use that node-sqlserver works on?